# How to upgrade Ext-4 to Ext-6 library

Tags: extjs

I want to upgrade Ext-4 to Ext-6 library and  We want to change the theme of the form to Triton in  project.

Answer (score 2):

Here is official Sencha's guide on migration from ExtJS4 to ExtJS5, using Sencha CMD:
https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/cmd_upgrade_five.html

And from ExtJS5 to ExtJS6:
https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/cmd_upgrade_guide.html

Also, get to know what is Microloader, which is one of the major changes in ExtJS5: https://docs.sencha.com/cmd/guides/microloader.html

From my personal experience migrating from ExtJS5 to ExtJS6 was very painful. There's a lot of small caveats like, `Ext.data.Store`, in ExtJS6, starts loading data with delay, if config `asynchronousLoad: false` not specified. Generally, I would recommend you to look at release notes for every version of ExtJS, that was released after the version you currently use, although not every change will be specified there.

Comment: How can i change the theme only, if we don't  want to change code ?

Comment: @Hemant I don't know if it's possible, at all, to apply new themes to older versions of ExtJS

Comment: can you please let me know Is there any way to simply upgrade step by step we can get EXT- 6

Comment: @Hemant No, surely, there is no easy way to upgrade. My migration from ExtJS5 to ExtJS6 took more than 2 weeks. I suspect, it would be even harder to migrate from ExtJS4

Comment: But i need to upgrade, then what difficulties i have  to face with code changes  (if i upgrade ext-4 to ext-6) ?

Comment: @Hemant As I said, major one is, you will need to adapt Microloader(basically, it's bundler). As for smaller changes, there is a lot of them, so you need to consult release notes of ExtJS. If you concerned about project structure, you can use ExtJS4 style structure in ExtJS6 project.